# Why is my HTML alignment changing when I'm including a footer?

Tags: php, html, css, alignment, text-alignment

I am designing a website/software using PHP. I have written the code for a few pages, however when I include the footer.php file, the HTML text alignment seems to be changing and I'm not sure why. I am also attaching the images for better understanding. This is happening for all the pages on which I'm including the footer, I have mentioned the code below for footer from the image.

[Before Adding the Footer the text is center aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5APDc.png)
[After including footer.php the text automatically becomes left aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hRK3.png)

footer.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/leaf.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <style>
            i {
                width: 15px;
                height: 15px;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="bg-dark text-center text-white mb-4">
      <!-- Grid container -->
      <div class="container p-4">
        <!-- Section: Social media -->
        <section class="mb-4">
          <!-- Facebook -->
          <a title="Facebook" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-floating m-1" href="https://www.facebook.com/SaiNirmanBiocoal" role="button"
            ><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i
          ></a>
          
        </section>
        <!-- Section: Social media -->
        
 
        <!-- Section: Form -->
        <section class="mb-4">
          <img src="assets/images/SNB-latest.png" style="height:50px;width: auto;" alt="Sai Nirman Biocoal Logo">
        </section>
        <!-- Section: Form -->
        

        <!-- Section: Text -->
        <section class="mb-4">
          <p>
              Sai Nirman Biocoal<br>
              "Fueling the Future with Sustainable Energy"
          </p>
        </section><br>
        <!-- Section: Text -->

        <!-- Section: Links -->
        <section class="">
          <!--Grid row-->
          <div class="row ">
            <!--Grid column-->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
              <h5 class="text-uppercase">Customer Care</h5>

              <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">FAQs</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="https://sainirmanbiocoal.com/privacy.html" class="text-white">Privacy Policy</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">Terms of Service</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Grid column-->

            <!--Grid column-->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
              <h5 class="text-uppercase">SNB Website</h5>

              <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">Products</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">Careers</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Grid column-->

            <!--Grid column-->
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-md-0">
              <h5 class="text-uppercase">My Account</h5>

              <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">Sign Out</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">Reset Password</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#!" class="text-white">Ledger</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <!--Grid column-->

          </div>
          <!--Grid row-->
        </section>
        <!-- Section: Links -->
      </div>
      <!-- Grid container -->

      <div class="text-center p-3" style="background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
        <a class="text-white" href="https://www.sainirmanbiocoal.com/">sainirmanbiocoal.com</a>
      </div>
    </footer>
    <!-- Footer -->

    <script src="assets/vendors/jquery/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to add style tag in footer.php and define the html and body properties as center align since the problem seems to be due to the footer code for some reason but it does not work. I even tried including header.php again at the end instead of footer.php and the same problem occurs, so I'm not really sure as to what exactly might be the issue.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap is this using?

Comment: Are you really restarting the HTML page from the beginning in footer.php? Hasn't the HTML page started long since? I would expect only the `<footer> ..... </footer>` section in footer.php.

Comment: And where is the actual text shown in your screenshots, above the footer? Please present a _proper_ [mre] of your issue, when asking questions like this.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Making the change to start the footer file with <footer> tag instead of restarting the HTML page actually solved the problem. Thank You

Comment: A HTML document can only have one html, head and body tag. Otherwise, it's effectively two documents, and that's not going to end well when your browser assumes it's going to be parsing one single document.